# Float multiples Vector in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Assume I have implemented a Vector class. In C++ it is possible to do "scaling" in natural math expressions by overloading operator* at global scope:

```
template <typename T>    // T can be int, double, complex<>, etc.
Vector operator*(const T& t, const Vector& v);
template <typename T>    // T can be int, double, complex<>, etc.
Vector operator*(const Vector& v, const T& t);
```

However, when it goes to Ruby, since parameters are not typed, it would be possible to write

```
class Vector
  def *(another)
    case another
    when Vector then ...
    when Numeric then ...
    end
  end
end
```

This allows Vector * Numeric, but not Numeric * Vector. Is there a way of solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Using `Numeric` rather than `Numerical` in my reply.]

The most general way to do this is to add a `coerce` method to `Vector`. When Ruby encounters `5 * your_vector`, the call to `5.*(your_vector)` fails, it will then call `your_vector.coerce(5)`. Your `coerce` method will pass back two items and the `*` method will be retried on those items.

Conceptually, something like this happens after the `5.*(your_vector)` failure:

```
first, second = your_vector.coerce(5)
first.*(second)
```

The most simple approach is to pass back `your_vector` as the first item and `5` as the second.

```
def coerce(other)
  case other
  when Numeric
    return self, other
  else
    raise TypeError, "#{self.class} can't be coerced into #{other.class}"
  end
end
```

That works for commutative operations, but not so well for non-commutative operations. If you have a simple, self-contained program that only needs `*` to work, you could get away with it. If you're developing a library or need something more generic, and it makes sense to transform `5` into a `Vector`, you can do that in `coerce`:

```
def coerce(other)
  case other
  when Numeric
    return Vector.new(other), self
  else
    raise TypeError, "#{self.class} can't be coerced into #{other.class}"
  end
end
```

This is a much more robust solution, if it makes semantic sense. If it doesn't make semantic sense, you can create an intermediate type that you can transform `Numeric` into that does know how to multiply with `Vector`. This [the approach that `Matrix` takes](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/lib/matrix.rb#L1268).

As a last resort, you can pull out the big guns and use [`alias_method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-alias_method) to redefine `*` on `Numeric` to handle `Vector`. I'm not going to add the code for this approach, since doing it wrong will lead to disaster, and I haven't thought though any edge cases involved.